# Reference list of figures with autoref in continuous text

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, hyperref, bookmarks

How can I create a reference with `\autoref{}` to the *list of figures* (or *glossary*, *list of tables*, etc.) within continuous text?

### Minimal Example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!htbp]
        \caption{Hello World}
    \end{figure}

    … bla bla bla have a look at the \autoref{??} bla bla bla …

    \listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Comment: `lof` is an unnumbered section in `article`. How do you expect to refer to it? However, you may put `\phantomsection \label{listoffigures}` just before the `\listoffigures`. But then you have to train `autoref` as it doesn't know the name.

Comment: Should it be a reference or a link instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `\autoref` is the easiest way to deal with this.  This simplest approach is to use `\hyperref` combined with a `\phantomsection` and `\label`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tbp]
  \centering
  \vrule height 1cm width 1cm
  \caption{Hello World}
\end{figure}

\dots have a look at the
\hyperref[listoffigures]{\listfigurename} for\dots 

\phantomsection\label{listoffigures}
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

If you want the automation of `autoref`, the `cleveref` package is probably easier to customize.  It uses `\cref` rather than `\autoref`.  Defining a new counter gives a way to hook in to this:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\newcounter{lofigs}
\crefformat{lofigs}{#2\listfigurename #3}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tbp]
  \centering
  \vrule height 1cm width 1cm
  \caption{Hello World}
  \label{fig:ex}
\end{figure}

\dots have a look at the \cref{listoffigures} for\dots see \cref{fig:ex}.

\refstepcounter{lofigs}\label{listoffigures}
\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

If you want to make this look like its completely automatic you could patch the `\listoffigures` command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\newcounter{lofigs}
\crefformat{lofigs}{#2\listfigurename #3}

\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\@starttoc}{\refstepcounter{lofigs}\label{listoffigures}\@starttoc}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tbp]
  \centering
  \vrule height 1cm width 1cm
  \caption{Hello World}
  \label{fig:ex}
\end{figure}

\dots have a look at the \cref{listoffigures} for\dots see \cref{fig:ex}.

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

In all cases you are going to have to make similar arrangements for the other lists your document may use.

Comment: Your first solution works perfect for my requirements and your other answers may help someone searching for the same.

Answer (score 2):

If the OP refers to `links` instead to a `reference`, this could be a solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\listfigurename}{\phantomsection\hypertarget{link::lof}{\listfigurename}}{}{}
\newcommand{\loflink}{\hyperlink{link::lof}{\listfigurename}}

\patchcmd{\listoftables}{\listtablename}{\phantomsection\hypertarget{link::lot}{\listtablename}}{}{}
\newcommand{\lotlink}{\hyperlink{link::lot}{\listtablename}}


\begin{document}
\listoftables
    \begin{figure}[!htbp]
        \caption{Hello World}
    \end{figure}
… bla bla bla have a look at the \loflink~ bla bla bla …whereas in \lotlink it is shown that...

\clearpage

\begin{table}
    \caption{Hello World - Table}
\end{table}


\listoffigures
```

\end{document}